# How to add FirebaseFirestoreSwift to workspace || Is FirebaseFirestoreSwift incompatible with React Native?

Tags: swift, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

I want to use Firestore in my app but if I add 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift' to my podfile then I get a pod install/update error:

> [!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:The Swift pod `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` depends upon
> `FirebaseFirestore`, which does not define modules. To opt into those
> targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from
> Swift when building as static libraries), you may set
> `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify
> `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

So I tried this:

```
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', :modular_headers => true
```

But just got the same error, so tried this:

```
pod 'Firebase/Firestore', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
```

But still got the same error, so tried this:

```
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
```

Now there's no error when installing the pods, but there's now a new linking error when building that wasn't there previously:

> Module map file
> '/Users/..../ios/Pods/Headers/Private/openssl_grpc/BoringSSL-GRPC.modulemap'
> not found

The app is a React Native app and the openssl_grpc must be being added as part of that.

So my question, how can I add FirebaseFirestoreSwift to the app if doing so messes up React Native?

Answer (score 1):

Try `use_frameworks!` or `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`.

More background at https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.9.0-beta/

Comment: Unfortunately adding use_frameworks! resulted in a pod update failure: "the .. target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries:" Using use_frameworks! :linkage => :static removed the GRPC.modulemap' linking error, but there's now another which is that the file "SKSwizzle.h" can't be found in FlipperKit, which is another React Native component

Comment: Ugh! You definitely need modules to use the Swift-implemented FirebaseFirestoreSwift. Unfortunately, it looks like there are other bugs exposed with each of the different CocoaPods options to turn them on. :(

Comment: Other than the SKSwizzle.h issue, I've seen the others before and none of them have easy solutions - so diving deeper into that one could be the best route.

Comment: Thanks for you assistance

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and added `use_frameworks!` , like Paul already posted... This works for me.

My podfile looks like this now.

```
target 'HiProject' do
use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase' 
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'EAIntroView'
pod 'lottie-ios'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me as of october 2022 with Xcode 14.0.1, RNFirebase 16.2.0 and RN 0.66.4:

```rb
target 'MyApp' do
  # ...

  # Add these two lines
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true

  # ...
end
```